# SSL certificate verification is failed and not able to login to application

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, web-applications

I am trying to login to a application via a code but I am getting the below error

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import requests

ssl.\_create_default_https_context = ssl.\_create_unverified_context

login_url = 'https://x.x.x.x/xxxxx'
session = requests.Session()
response = requests.get(login_url,verify=False)

response = session.get(login_url)

login_data = {
'username' : 'xxx',
'password': 'xxx'
}

if 'Welcome' in login_response.text:
print('Login successful')
else:
print('Login failed.')
```

where is the mistake in my code or what am I missing?

I was trying to login to application but seems login fails due to SSL certificate issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 467, in \_make_request
self.\_validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in \_validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connection.py", line 642, in connect
sock_and_verified = \_ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py", line 513, in \_ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class.\_create(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\ssl.py", line 1041, in \_create
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\ssl.py", line 1310, in do_handshake
self.\_sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (\_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
response = self.\_make_request(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 491, in \_make_request
raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (\_ssl.c:1129)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\adapters.py", line 486, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\retry.py", line 515, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(\_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore\[arg-type\]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '\[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (\_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\Scripts\\templates\\datapush2.py", line 27, in \<module\>
login_response = session.post(login_url , data=login_data)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\sessions.py", line 637, in post
return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, \*\*send_kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\mukavya\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\adapters.py", line 517, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '\[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (\_ssl.c:1129)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```